# Is this for of session management correct?

Tags: struts2, session-state

I am using struts2 for my web application. Now for session management we are actually keeping the user id in session (i.e. the DB identifier) and while logging out we remove this user id from session object. Our session object (which encapsulates the user id) is implementing sessionaware interface and therefore i guess we get all the session related information automatically in the session map.

My basic grudge is for logging out. we are just removing the user id from session and not really "invalidating" the session, something like session.invalidate().

I am new to struts2 and even this product prototype which i am describing. So could someone please tell me if removing the user id from session is sufficient and if not then what kind of security hazards i might have? Should i also do session.invalidate on logout?

Comment: removing the id from the session is what more than enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, removing the user id from the session should be enough to tell your application that the user is signed out. If you can, I would also recommend removing all other session variables and invalidating the session cookie. This will prevent any unexpected behavior if your code uses other session variables without first checking if the user id is set.

I normally store the user id in the session to indicate that the user is signed in and to tell me who the user is. If this value is not set, then I kick the user to the sign in page.

Answer (score 0):

Never do `session.invalidate();` just setting an empty value to the session attribute is sufficient (no need to remove the attribute also !). Your check should be like this:

```
if( is the attribute present is session)
    if( is the value of attribute null) {
         go to login page;
    }
    else {
        go to welcome page;
    }
}
else {
     go to login page;
}
```

Using `session.invalidate()` means you are telling the looged-out user has no valid session, he is a curse to our website :))

UPDATE :
From HTTPSession [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

> invalidate()
>
> Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

So you will get an error while trying to access the variables stored in the session scope (if you have any) after session.invalidate()

Comment: wouldnt session.validate() flush out all the data that was present in the session and thus helping GC ??

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with `session.invalidate()` (because there's nothing wrong with `session.invalidate()`. You'll need to back up your claim that it should never be done.

Comment: @arya Removing objects from session (hence references to those objects) does the same thing--there's no additional *benefit* GC-wise, other than calling invalidate removes *all* session values instead of relying on the developer to remember what all was put in the session.

Comment: @DaveNewton and arya I have updated about my opinion behind not to use `session.invalidate()`. please correct me if I am wrong here :)

Comment: I still don't understand why you think it's *wrong* to use it--it simply isn't. Its purpose in life is to invalidate the session and remove the current user's objects, which is almost *always* what you want to do on a logout, and solves leaky session issues when you don't manually remove all objects put there for that user.

Comment: well, it looks difficult to tell what OP wants to do on a logout without more information on his application. In my applications, I never had to use `invalidate()`and those never faced any leaky session issues as you mentioned.

Comment: dave, thats exactly my point... i feel invalidate() is essential. i mean noone know what all stuff was present in the session object... what all attributes were added by developers. the idea behind invalidate() in my opinion is to be 100% sure of all information w.r.t the user who's logging out should be flushed out. thats why i was looking for opinion, though as i said above, i would like to have invalidate()

Comment: @arya, very good point. but no reason of repeating same thing again and again. And if your fellow developers cannot communicate about what they have added into session, its a miss-communication between your team. Let me remind you this is a site for questions which can be answered. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ is for debate and discussions.